# Put correct scaled marks on graph

Tags: java, graph, processing

I have a simple graph in Processing (Java). It displays values between 0 and 1024 as a green lines with various heights.
Have a look:  [image]

I want to put marks on the graph to increase orientation. This means a want a grey horizontal lines marking for example 0, 256, 512, 768 and 1024. I want to display different ammount of marks depending on window size. This should be decided by minimal 100px of distance between two marks.
I can't figure out how to calculate this from height. This is the second time I face this problem and I never solved it clearly and succesfully.
Here is my try:

```
  //How many marks can we display at maximum
  byte no_marks = (byte)(height/100);  
  //I just guess I always want 1,3,5... here, so there will be a mark in the middle
  if(no_marks%2==0)
    no_marks--;
  //Calculate how many pixels will be between my marks
  short mark_distance = (short)(height/no_marks);
  //Now calculate the value distance between marks
  short mark_step = (short)(1024/(no_marks+1));

  textSize(32);
  //I go from 1 to max-1 because 0 and 1024 wouldn't fit on screen
  for(byte i=1; (i+1)<no_marks; i+=1) {
     //Draw light blue text
     text((i*mark_step), 5,mark_distance*i); 
     fill(0, 102, 153);
  }
```

Comment: I tried to think. As I've stated above, I cannot figure out, how to calculate it.

Comment: oh you've got to change the `no_marks` variable name to `marks_num` or something. It took a while before I grasped that `no_marks` isn't representing a state of no marks at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your canvas?

Let's assume it is 1200 pixels high.
If you are getting values from 0-1024 from your Serial input, you want to graph those from the bottom of the screen ([height](http://processing.org/reference/height.html) in Processing) to 1024. Let's assume that you centre it, so offset it by 88 pixels:

int graphHeight = 1024;
int baseLine = height - ((height - graphHeight) /2); // 1112

This is now your starting point from which to draw everything.
Then lets assume that you follow the same formula to make your gray markers:

int quarterLine = baseLine - 256; // 856
int halfLine = baseLine - 512; // 600
int threeQuarterLine = baseLine - 768; // 344
int topLine = baseLine - graphHeight; // 88

If your canvas is less than that height, just scale accordingly...

Make sense ?

Then, draw them with the line() method:

stroke(155);
line(0, quarterLine, width, quarterLine);

etc...

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but I guess I did not ask the question properly and you helped me much even with this, thank you.